# "Property 'heatLayer' does not exist on type [Leaflet]" on --prod build

Tags: angular, leaflet, heatmap

I'm trying to build my angular 9 project, using leaflet's [heat map library](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat).
when compiling it works great, but when I try to *--prod build* it, I get the following error:

> ERROR in heat-map-map.component.ts:112:7 - error TS2339: Property 'heatLayer' does not exist on type 'typeof import("projectPath/ClientApp/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index")'.

Here's my code:

```
var convertedData: [number, number, number][];

convertedData = this.grid.map(g => [g.lat, g.lon, this.data.find(d => d.toID == g.gid)?.time_sec]);

// THIS is the important line
L.heatLayer(convertedData, { max: max.time_sec }).addTo(this.markersLayer);
 
this.markersLayer.addTo(this.map);
```

and my imports:

```
import *  as L from 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js';
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to import types for that plugin. Otherwise easy workaround is `(L as any).heatLayer(...`